# Does SQL Agent need to be running in order to take manual SQL backups?

Tags: sql-server, disaster-recovery, database-backup

If we have a situation where SQL Agent fails to start, will we still be able to take a full manual SQL backup?

I don't mean scheduled backups and maintenance plans, just plain Right Click > Tasks > Backup (in SQL Management Studio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a backup from Right Click > Tasks > Backup in SSMS you do not require the SQL agent to be running (this backup method works in SQL Express which does not allow the Agent to run).

Comment: @TimS You may also use the `sqlcmd` utility to run a SQL script designed to back up DBs, right from a Windows Scheduled Task -- Not as elegant as SQL Agent, but quite functional on SQL Express installs.